# jQuery droppable / draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

At the moment I have a set of divs, generated dynamically by php and all having their ids starting with 'itembox', with a count number appended. I have a droppable garbage bin area on the page so that the user can delete an individual itembox by fdragging and dropping on to the bin.

My problem is that the droppable won't seem to activate when I drag the original, while it will function (perfectly) when I have helper: 'clone' set. Unfortunately, though, when dragging, the cloning function takes its clone from the first iteration of the itembox, no matter which itembox is actually dragged.

So I'm looking for a solution to either make the droppable accept an original or force the cloning function to take its clone from the itembox actually dragged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem must lie in the accept option of your droppable initializer. Just try the following:

```
$('#mydroppable').droppable(
{
    accept: function() { return true; },
    drop: function () { alert("Dropped!"); }
});
```

Now this will accept everything, so you should probably implement some filtering in the accept function but none the less this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.srcfield').draggable({
        revert: true    
    });

    $('#trash').droppable({
        accept : ".srcfield",
        over: function(){
            $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('over');
        },`enter code here`
        out: function(){
            $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out');
        },
        drop: function(ev, ui){
            //var answer = confirm('Delete this item?');
            var theTitle = $(ui.draggable).attr("title");
            $(this).html("<u>"+theTitle+"</u><br/> is deleted!");
        }
    });
});
</script>


<body>
    <div id="trash" class="out">
            <span>Trash</span>
    </div>
    <div id="sourcefields">
            <div class="srcfield" title="First Name"><span>First Name</span></div>
            <div class="srcfield" title="Last Name"><span>Last Name</span></div>
            <div class="srcfield" title="Age"><span>Age</span></div>
    </div>
</body>
```